# Сравнение семейства ОС с помощью битовой маски

Tags: битовые-операции, ос

Пишу очень примитивный пакет для работы с окружением. Хотел задать семейство ОС через битмаски, чтобы легко можно было осуществить сравнение следующим способом:

```
FAMILY_UBUNTU & FAMILY_DEBIAN = FAMILY_UBUNTU & FAMILY_UNIX = [1..]
FAMILY_MAC & FAMILY_UNIX = [1..]
FAMILY_UBUNTU & FAMILY_MAC = 0
```

И словил мощнейший затуп в этом месте. Это же ведь вообще нереально, да?

Comment: Я даже понять не могу Вашу проблему. А можете сформулировать чуть яснее? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@sys_dev](/users/14618/sys_dev), мда, это точно невозможно, я очень-очень крепко затупил. Но вот что я хотел:

я хочу задать иерархию семейств ОС (простое дерево) так, чтобы через битовое сравнение определять, соответствует ли сравниваемая ОС выбранной ноде дерева или ее родителям. Если бы там не было ветвей, это выглядело бы так:

```
UNIX = 1
DEBIAN = 1 & 2
UBUNTU = 1 & 4

UBUNTU & DEBIAN = true
UBUNTU & UNIX = true
DEBIAN & UBUNTU = false
```